# Как пронумеровать записи от 1 до n в каждой группе?

Tags: mysql

Как мне переписать свой запрос так, чтобы выдавало :

```
+------+-----------+----+
| row  | type_manf | id |
+------+-----------+----+
|    1 |         1 |  1 |
|    2 |         1 |  6 |
|    3 |         1 | 18 |
|    4 |         1 |  8 |
|    5 |         1 | 10 |
|    1 |         2 | 24 |
|    2 |         2 | 21 |
|    3 |         2 | 13 |
|    4 |         2 |  7 |
|    5 |         2 | 11 |
|   1  |         3 | 23 |
|   2  |         3 | 12 |
|   1  |         4 | 16 |
|   2  |         4 |  4 |
|   1  |         5 |  2 |
|   2  |         5 | 25 |
|   1  |         7 | 15 |
|   1  |         8 | 17 |
+------+-----------+----+
```

Мой же запрос выдаёт:

```
+------+-----------+----+
| row  | type_manf | id |
+------+-----------+----+
|    1 |         1 |  1 |
|    2 |         1 |  6 |
|    3 |         1 | 18 |
|    4 |         1 |  8 |
|    5 |         1 | 10 |
|    6 |         2 | 24 |
|    7 |         2 | 21 |
|    8 |         2 | 13 |
|    9 |         2 |  7 |
|   10 |         2 | 11 |
|   11 |         3 | 23 |
|   12 |         3 | 12 |
|   13 |         4 | 16 |
|   14 |         4 |  4 |
|   15 |         5 |  2 |
|   16 |         5 | 25 |
|   17 |         7 | 15 |
|   18 |         8 | 17 |
+------+-----------+----+
```

Сам запрос:

```
select @i := @i+1 AS row, type_manf, id 
from contract, (select @i:=0) as z 
where stat=0 
order by 2;
```

Comment: Я не смог уловить логику групп в вашей таблице.

Comment: @LEQADA - для каждого нового `type_manf` счетчик `row` обнуляется и начинаяется снова с 1

Comment: @LEQADA ну группа у меня type_manf. Для каждой из этих групп колонка row начинает отсчет заново: от 1 до n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, что Вам подойдет:

```
select IF(type_manf<>@n, @i:=1, @i := @i+1) AS row, type_manf, id, @n:=type_manf
from contract, (select @i:=0,@n:=0) as z 
where stat=0 order by 2;
```

В `@n` храним последнее значение `type_manf`.
Если оно не равно текущему - ставим `@i` в единицу.
Если равно - увеличиваем на единицу.

### UPDATE

Только что выяснил, что присвоение пользовательских переменных (@i:=@i+1) происходит **ДО** сортировки `ORDER BY`.
Поэтому, если использовать переменные для порядковой нумерации строк, в некоторых случаях нумерация может работать неверно, особенно если в запросе присутствует `ORDER BY` или `JOIN`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. А где можно почитать про такие крутые штуки? Решаю sql-ex(уже 50+ задач), но там еще не встречал такого.

Comment: это называется "пользовательские переменные". Можете начать с общего описания вот тут: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-user-variables.html. Однако я о них не так много нашел. Во многиз местах жалуются, что они сильно тормозят систему на больших запросах. Так что будьте осторожны.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку :)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй

```
select dense_rank() over(partition by type_manf order by type_manf) as "row"
     , *
  from #t1
 order by type_manf
```

Comment: В mysql нет же dense_rank(). Из-за этого собственно и спросил.

Comment: ну тогда тэг `mysql` поставьте :)

Comment: @cyadvert прошу прощения, добавил.

Answer (score 0):

не стоит благодарности)
в общем виде ответ будет таким

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type_manf ORDER BY id) as row
    type_manf,
    id
FROM contract
ORDER BY type_manf, id
```

но для поставленного вопроса будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type_manf) as row
    type_manf,
    id
FROM contract
ORDER BY type_manf
```